# How to fix laravel update endpoint?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to update a user.

Here is my model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'user_type',
        'username'
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

Here is the update controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $user->update($request->all());

    return response()->json($user, 200);
}
```

Here is the api.php:

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'users',
    'middleware' => ['cors', 'json.response', 'auth:api']
], function () {
    Route::put('/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
});
```

I'm sending request with VSCode extension like this:

```
PUT {{server}}/users/2
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {{token}}

{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
}
```

But it's not changing the `name`. I couldn't understand what am I missing.

I have tried to change the selecting User data on my own. But not working.

I think it's about not extending `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;`.

Comment: No errors? returns `200`?

Comment: @MohamedGamalEldin yes

Comment: Is the route triggered properly? What does `$user` contain before calling `update`? Does `$user` contain what it should after calling `update`?

Comment: @NicoHaase let me update the question.

Comment: So, then let's ask again: what have you tried to resolve th problem? Where are you stuck? Why not dump `$user` to check whether it contains the proper content? Why not start a proper debugger to step through the code?

Comment: "I think it's about not extending use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model" - if you already assume that, why not check it out to see whether this resolves the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Probably controller can't find $user. Change your code to $user = auth('api')->user(); in update function. And delete User $user from brackets.

Comment: It's in the Route::Group. But you're right. I should have mentioned it.

Comment: Can you try to change `$user->update($request->all());` this code in controller with `$user->update(['name' => $request->name]);`

Comment: I tried. Nothing changed.